# SQL Server open source query analyzer

Tags: .net-4.0, open-source, sql-server-2008-r2, query-analyzer

My team is going to be working on some internal tools for various teams in our department, and there are a number of database-specific tasks I'd like to support (SQL Server 2008 R2/SQL Server 2012).

I don't want to spend a bunch of time duplicating existing UI functionality, just want to add some helpful features. Initially we were thinking of writing some add-ins for SSMS, but it turns out to be not very well documented.

It occurred to me that there might be some open source query analyzer type projects that we could start with. I found QASharp on CodeProject, but I was wondering if there was anything newer. We have 2008 R2 and will also be using 2012 soon, so I'd like to start with something more recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of searching, I found what looks to be a viable candidate for what I'm looking for in **Query ExPlus**.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/queryexplus/?source=dlp